# Calling makefiles from Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

I am new to shell script. I want to call a list of make files from Shell script  in a particular order. For each makefile I want to get the result (make is success or failure). If any error I want to stop the script execution. If it is success I have to run the next makefile.

Comment: Like `make1 && make2 && make3`?

Comment: Or `make -f makefile1 && make -f makefile2 && ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A common idiom is to create a shell script with `set -e`; this will cause the script to exit on the first error.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
make -f Makefile1
make -f Makefile2
:
```

If you need more control over the script overall, maybe remove `set -e` and instead explicitly exit on `make` failure:

```
make -f Makefile1 || exit
make -f Makefile2 || exit
```

To reduce code duplication, create a loop:

```
for f in Makefile1 Makefile2; do
    make -f "$f" || exit
done
```

Just to be explicit, the `||` "or" and `&&` "and" connectives are shorthand for

```
if make -f Makefile1; then
     : "and" part
else
    : "or" part
fi
```

Finally, the behavior you describe sounds exactly like how Make itself behaves. Perhaps a top-level Makefile would actually be a suitable solution for your scenario?

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile1
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
make -f makefile1
make -f makefile2
```

to run make files in order

to save the output of each makefile

```
make -f makefile1 >> output1
make -f makefile2 >> output2
```

to check the result after each make file

```
make -f makefile1 >> output1
```

after this line script use
    echo $?  this in combination with if. if echo$? result zero then your make success so if echo$? result zero then run next file other wise exit

Comment: It might be helpful to also log the errors, i.e. `make -f makefile1 &>> output1`

Comment: The `&>>file` redirection is not portable; some shells support this form as syntactic sugar, but frankly the portable `>>file 2>&1` seems perfectly fine to me.